# Setting Default Value Strategy with Multiple Source Object in MapStruct

Tags: java, mapstruct

I want to generate null checks on mapped properties of my source objects and set to a default value if indeed the source property is null.

I have tried to use NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_DEFAULT on @Mapper as well as on @Mapping targets but the generated code did not include the default setters..

So basically what I am trying to achieve is:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface OperationDataMapper {

    OperationDTO from(Object 1 o1, Object2 o2);
}
```

So that my generated code becomes:

```
@Component
public class OperationDataMapperImpl implements OperationDataMapper {

    @Override 
    public OperationDTO from(Object 1 o1, Object2 o2) {
        if ( o1 == null && o2 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        OperationDTO operationDTO = new OperationDTO();

        if ( o1 != null ) {
            if(o1.getProp1() != null) {
                operationDTO.setProp1( o1.getProp1() )
            } else {
                operationDTO.setProp1( "" ) // if property is a string for example
            }
            .
            .
        }
    
        if ( o2 != null ) {
            if(o2.getProp2() != null) {
                operationDTO.setProp2( o2.getProp2() )
            } else {
                operationDTO.setProp2( "" ) // if property is a string for example
            }
            .
            .
        }
    
        return operationDTO;
    }
}
```

I didn't write my example with the default value strategy like the documentation points out because I it did not work on my attempts to map the nested properties with null values.. Interesting enough, the NullValueCheckStrategy works without any problems but the NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy does not.

I have also tried setting them using a @BeanMapping with no avail.

If someone could please point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy` is meant to be used for update mappings. If you want that to be applied you'll have to provide the `OperationDTO` through `@MappingTarget`.

The only way to achieve what you are looking for is to use `Mapping#defaultValue` or `Mapping#defaultExpression`